# AWS ELB Stripping all the POST parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, http-post, elastic-load-balancer

Is there any setting where all the POST request parameters are trimmed by the AWS load balancer?

It works fine when we send the requests as a payload, but all the parameters are missing when it's part of the URL.

Please help.

Comment: What web server are you running behind the ELB? This is probably where the issue is, ELB just forwards requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no problem with the AWS ELB, we are using tomcat 8 and setting `maxPostSize = -1 (no limit)` resolved it. So, tomcat was limiting the size of the POST request.